# Best practice or alternatives to handling sub/side nav in a mobile site

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, sidebar

I am looking for what would be the best way to handle a websites sidebar in a mobile website template.

I am going to be involved in a redesign for a large web site (approximately 10,000+ pages) that will be responsive. The site has a side nav which can grow to 10+ links (child pages) in the navigation. Links will always be only 1 level deep and in some cases may be the only way to navigate to the specific page.

Normally in a responsive site we would just stack the links on top of each other either before or after the content. I am in favor of after so the user doesn't need to scroll too far to get to content.

The main navigation (on desktop mode it's a dropdown) is a button in the top right (≡) that expands when clicked. This is more of a global navigation where as the subnav is relevant to the current page.

Edit:
The sites main navigation links to different departments within the company and the sub navigation links to pages under the current page/category being viewed.

Comment: Can you provide more information? What is the relationship between the main navigation and the side navigation? What kind of website is it (gives context of the content of the menu)? Any information which makes it clearer what your difficulties and restrictions are.

Answer (score 1):

A very common and usable practice for narrow screens is to put the nav menu in a drop down that's accessible via a 3 bar button ("≡", AKA "hamburger" button).  The button is usually on the very upper left or right of the page.  The "hamburger" button has become an established convention I think.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned we have this type of navigation for our main navigation. I'll go back and edit.

Comment: Oh I get it.  Sorry for sounding a little pedantic.